# Debian 11: Fixing Bluetooth Headset Input Device with A2DP Profile - Setting /etc/bluetooth/main.conf MultiProfile = multiple breaks bluetooth service

Tags: debian, audio, bluetooth, systemctl

I'm trying to fix an issue where my bluetooth headset can't act as a microphone while using the A2DP profile. Everything I've been looking up has told me that you need to enable multiple profiles and it should automatically switch between A2DP and HSP/HFP when a program requests the microphone.

Well every time I uncomment the line MultiProfile = multiple and restart the bluetooth service, it doesn't work until that line gets commented out again.

So why does everything I look up show that this is the solution, and it should be working without fail? And if this isn't the correct solution, how should I go about fixing my bluetooth headset sound quality/microphone issue?

[image]

Comment: please post the text, not a screenshot of text